# what is my mistake in estimating CR integral by Jordan s lemma

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

as part of evaluating this integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x.\sin(x)}{x^2
+9} \,dx$, I reach to use Jordan Lemma to show :
$$|\int_{-R}^R \frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2
+9} \,dz|\le\int_{-R}^R |\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2
+9}| \,|dz|\le\frac{\pi.R^2}{R^2-9}$$
clearly as $R\rightarrow\infty, $ the integral above does not tend to zero! what is my mistake?

Comment: Your $\mathbf{ML}$ bound is too weak, and you never actually apply Jordan's Lemma. What is the problem you are having? Nothing you wrote is wrong, but all you've done is show the integral is finite

Comment: Thanks to @Chamsi , I noticed my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a function $ f $ on $ \mathbb{R} $ as follows : $$ \left(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\right),\ f\left(t\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xt}}{x^{2}+9}\,\mathrm{d}x} $$

Fixing $ t\in\mathbb{R} $ and $ R> 3 $, then integrating $ f_{t}:z\mapsto\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}zt}}{z^{2}+9} $ on $ \gamma_{R}=\left[-R,R\right]\cup\mathscr{C}_{R} $, where $ \mathscr{C}_{R}=\left\lbrace z:\left|z\right|=R,\ \mathcal{Im}\left(z\right)\geq 0\right\rbrace $, will give us a closed form for our $ f \cdot $

We have : $$ 2\pi\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{Res}\left(f_{t},3\mathrm{i}\right)=\oint_{\gamma_{R}}{f_{t}\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}=\int_{-R}^{R}{f_{t}\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}+\int_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{f_{t}\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z} $$

Since : $$ \left|\int_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{f_{t}\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}\right|\leq\int_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{\left|f_{t}\left(z\right)\right|\left|\mathrm{d}z\right|}\leq\frac{1}{R^{2}-9}\int_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{\left|\mathrm{d}z\right|}=\frac{1}{R^{2}-9}\int_{0}^{\pi}{R\,\mathrm{d}\theta}=\frac{\pi R}{R^{2}-9}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow }0 $$

And : $$ 2\pi\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{Res}\left(f_{t},3\mathrm{i}\right)=2\pi\mathrm{i}\lim_{z\to 3\mathrm{i}}{\left(z-3\mathrm{i}\right)f_{t}\left(z\right)}=2\pi\mathrm{i}\lim_{z\to 3\mathrm{i}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}zt}}{z+3\mathrm{i}}}=\frac{\pi\,\mathrm{e}^{-3t}}{3} $$

Tending $ R $ to infinity, we get : $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f_{t}\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\pi\,\mathrm{e}^{-3t}}{3} $$

And hence, for any real $ t $, we have : $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{x\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xt}}{x^{2}+9}\,\mathrm{d}x}=-\mathrm{i}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\partial f_{t}}{\partial t}\left(t,x\right)\mathrm{d}x}=-\mathrm{i}f'\left(t\right)=\pi\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{e}^{-3t} $$

Taking the imaginary part, we get that $ \forall t\in\mathbb{R} $ : $$ \fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{x\sin{\left(xt\right)}}{x^{2}+9}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\pi\,\mathrm{e}^{-3t}\end{array}$} $$

Comment: Oh, I see this approach is totally new to me. all the examples I hve seen so far ar having sinx or cos x in numerator only. I am just trying to understand the last step: "And hence, for any real t, we have :"why are we multiplying an x by $f_t$

Comment: Differentiating $ f_{t} $ with respect to $ t $ will give us the factor $ x \cdot $

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where your difficulty lies, but Jordan's lemma applies to continuous functions $f(z)=e^{iaz}g(z)$ defined on the contour $C=C_R \cup [-R;R]$ where $C_R$ is the upper half circle of radius $R$. It then states that:
$$|\int_{C_R}f(z)dz| \le \frac{\pi}{a}\max_{z\in C_R}{|g(z)|}$$

If you compute this upper bound you will indeed see that the integral tends to $0$ as $R\to \infty$.

At last, we have:

$$\int_Cf(z)dz=\int_{C_R}f(z)dz+\int_{-R}^Rf(z)dz$$

We conclude by taking the limit in R and using the residue theorem. Is it clearer now?